# Images aren't showing in Vercel Deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

When I use the 'Live Server' to run my application the Images look fine in my local server, but after deploying the same **react/next** application to vercel, the images aren't getting rendered properly which are present in the public folder.

```
<div className="content">
      <div className="cards">
        {jsonData.map((info) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={info.id}>
              <div className="card-head">
                <img src="./06.png" />
                <div className="icon-body">
                  <FiGithub className="git-icon" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h3>{info.name}</h3>
              <div className="desc">{info.description}</div>
              <div className="stack">{info.stack}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Expected Output (in Local Server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQInf.png)

[Vercel Deployed Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qqc5.png)

Comment: try changing  dot slash `./` to slash `/` only

Comment: I Tried the solution that you suggested, it still doesn't work.

Comment: There could be problems in your routing if you have a custom config for your routes

Comment: Move the image to the `public` folder, then reference it with `src="/06.png"`.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening due to the folder structure. I have faced the same issue before.

You can add structure like **/public/static/images** and put your images inside like below:

```
<img src={"/static/images/test.png"} alt="" />
```

Comment: What if they are online hosted on a cdn and I link them directly?

Answer (score 1):

So I just solved this myself. First, you should check if your images are loading in the `.next/static/media/` folder. Every time you save, this acts like a `dist/` folder for your project before deployment.

I recommend that you modularly import your image using the same path you have in your example. Ill show you and example:

```
import img06 from './06.png'      // importing path modularly

<div className="content">
      <div className="cards">
        {jsonData.map((info) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={info.id}>
              <div className="card-head">
                <img src={img06} />              // src as var
                <div className="icon-body">
                  <FiGithub className="git-icon" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <h3>{info.name}</h3>
              <div className="desc">{info.description}</div>
              <div className="stack">{info.stack}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

You will know if it will load on deployment if you see your filename, a hash, and then the file type extension at the end.

As an example, if I loaded 06.png, it should pop up something like this in your
`.next/static/media/` folder:

`06.f9e5c945.png`

Try deploying and see if it works! If it does, I would really appreciate if you were to select my answer as the correct answer, as this will be my first accepted answer or StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Next JavaScript solution**

If you are using next JavaScript add this to your `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ["images.pexels.com","miro.medium.com", "www.cnet.com"],
    },
  }
```

**Explanation**

In order to retrieve the images from a website to store them on cache for faster load time, next JavaScript needs you to provide the root directory so that you don't have to edit it for every image in the same website, thus you must declare the website from which you'll be retrieving the image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is nextjs dont have images avalible at build time so you have to import them at top and the use them in src attribute

Answer (score 0):

I did this and my image displayed: The first thing i recommend is that the image should be in the public folder, then the file extension should be preceded by a backslash for example /filename.extension

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with files.

I initially exported `.png` screenshots as `.svg` and imported them into my project. I later realized that safari can't render those in HQ. So I changed  file extension inside project folder `.svg` -> `.png` which wasn't a proper way to do it.

I fixed it by exporting screenshots in Figma in `.png` format, reimported them to the project and images were displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're adding all your assets inside the Public folder.
Your file path should be like /file-name.extension

This will definitely work.